# Expression Func with two input parameters for generic method

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, generics

I want to integrate this expression

```
Expression<Func<Customer, string, bool>> paramCompareFunc = (cust, name) => cust.Company == name;
```

For this

```
private bool IsUnique<Entity>(DbSet<Entity> set, 
   string param, 
   Expression<Func<Entity, string, bool>> paramCompareFunc) 
where Entity : class
{
  var query = set.Where(paramCompareFunc); // how I can pass param to expression?
  // var query = set.Where(paramCompareFunc(param)); // error here
...
```

How I can pass the second parameter to the expression? 
I want to define different compare expressions for different entities (they don't have any same name field) and to have a possibility to pass this expression into my generic function.

Comment: `set.Where(e => paramCompareFunc(e, param));`? Although not every `Entity` is a `Customer`, will you make the func generic also?

Comment: @Charlieface `paramCompareFunc` is an `Expression` and thus not invocable

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 And [`Queryable.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.where?view=net-5.0) takes an `Expression`

Comment: @Charlieface I know that. But... `paramCompareFunc(e, param)` is invalid and won't compile since you can't invoke an `Expression<Func<,>>` *as if* it were a method/delegate, even in the context of an expression

Answer (score 1):

The "easy" way is by changing your api to use a factory method to build the `Expression` you actually need;

```cs
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> GetCompareFunc(string name) => (cust) => cust.Company == name;
```

While you could use `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` to swap the name parameter with a constant, that would have a negative impact on [performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-constant#dynamically-constructed-queries).

Comment: Also if you have a bunch of types that each have a Name field, you should consider defining an interface. That way you don't need to write a bunch of almost identical expressions.